# Can I pass a protected function as a callable?

Tags: php, callback, scope

I have a function which takes a callable parameter:

```
public static function setup(Router $router, Injector $injector, callable $toRouterCallable): void
```

I want to call it from another class and pass a **protected** parent function as the callable parameter. I tried three approaches, but they all fail:

```
Routes::setup($router, $injector, $this->toRouterCallable); // Undefined property '$toRouterCallable' 
Routes::setup($router, $injector, parent::toRouterCallable); // Undefined class constant 'toRouterCallable'
Routes::setup($router, $injector, [$this, 'toRouterCallable']); // Argument 3 passed setup() must be callable, array given
```

How can I pass the parent function to this function?

Comment: What exactly is a "parent function"? That third one should work just fine, assuming that code is inside a class method where `$this` exists.

Comment: As noted, your third one works: https://3v4l.org/C3ZWI

Comment: Or, do you have a child class that overrides that method, and you want the callable to bypass your override and go straight to the parent?

Comment: @ChrisHaas you are right, this does work. However, it [fails](https://3v4l.org/5EMRQ) when I add access modifiers. I will update my question to clarify that I'm using `protected`.

Comment: If the method is `protected`, then yeah, you can't pass it as callback to be called by something else; because `protected` methods can't be called from somewhere else.

Comment: @deceze I never considered that a possibility because I've been spoiled by Java lambdas. Please post an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Well, the _solution_ is to pass some wrapper function which calls the protected method. It's just been too long since I've actively touched PHP to come up with a quick sample that's up to date.

Comment: @deceze [this should work](https://pastecode.io/s/u8p81gka).

Comment: I'm fairly sure there's a more up-to-date shortcut lambda function syntax which would simplify that; but again, that came after my time with PHP…

Comment: @CardinalSystem How about `fn(object $controller, string $function) => $this->toRouterCallable($controller, $function)` ?

Comment: @NoahBoegli I like it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [First class callable syntax](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.first_class_callable_syntax.php) since PHP 8.1

```
Routes::setup($router, $injector, $this->toRouterCallable(...));
```

You can use the [Clousure](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.closure.php) class before that

```
$cl = Closure::fromCallable([$this, 'toRouterCallable']);
Routes::setup($router, $injector, $cl);
```

Comment: Yes, they will: https://3v4l.org/CoTQL